# Qt working with files

Tags: c++, qt, file

If my program needs to generate some files how can I make it in a way that it asks the user where to create the files?

For example to ask the user for an input of the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`.

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName):

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),
                            "/home/jana/untitled.png",
                            tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
```